# ExactTarget email will display in send preview but error at send time

Tags: marketing-cloud, send-email

I have a subset of emails that will not send from Send Preview, nor from a user-initiated send, but they will display in the Send Preview screen.

My emails are dynamically generated, and some subsets will send (that is, emails that are using particular content areas) but some will not.  Is there anything that Send Preview does differently than an actual send that might be able to tell us what is going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out!  We had some issues with RedirectTo() in some of our content areas.  Since that function is ignored during Send Preview, it was displaying, but not sending when the app choked on that function.

Thanks for reading!  (I'll accept this answer in 2 days, when I'm allowed -- unless someone has a better explanation!)